# Adding links to the image value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, image, hyperlink

There is a page on my companies website that pulls in an array of images and I am trying to link those images to a our other website, (our online shop).

The php code for each image looks like:

```
'black-tiger' => array(
            'name' => 'Black Tiger',
            'image' => 'Black-Tiger_Iced_DSC09856.jpg',
        ),
```

Is there a way to simply add a link to the image called up in the array?

---

Code provided by OP in later comment:

```
<div class="image"> 
<?php if ($drinkcategories[$key]['thumb']) { ?>
    <a href="/drinks/<?= $key ?>/">
        <img src="<?= $GLOBALS['pekoe_assets'] ?>/menucategorythumb/<?= $drinkcategories[$key]['thumb'] ?>" width="284" height="138" border="0" alt="">
    </a> 
<?php } else { ?> 
    <a href="/drinks/<?= $key ?>/">
        <img src="<?= $GLOBALS['pekoe_assets'] ?>/elements/pixelgraylite.gif" width="284" height="138" border="0" alt=""></a> <?php } ?> </div> <a href="/drinks/<?= $key ?>/" class="label interstate bggreen uc"><?= $drinkcategories[$key]['name'] ?>
    </a> 
<?php } ?> 
</div> <!-- ficuscr: Not sure why this was only in the else block... assume a mistake -->
```

Comment: What link would you like to add?

Comment: Kinda two parts, pass the new info, then make use of it.  Look at the code and how 'image' is assigned and then used, follow same pattern and add your hyperlink... You are showing the code for the first part, there is some code for the second part someplace, in a loop probably (looping on the array you've shown).   You can probably figure it out.

Comment: This some WordPress slide / banner thing perhaps?  Might be it supports a link and you just need to pass it in...  What I've been trying to say is these parameters you are assigning are used later to "render" things, might need to tweak things where that rendering happens too.

Comment: This a framework, wordpress, custom code?

Answer (score 0):

I'll make some assumptions then and try and steer you in the right direction.  Sounds like you might be in a little over your head or at least have phrased your question a little broadly.

...You've got an array that can be thought of as a collection of parameters which are going to be translated into those images you see on the page, rendered HTML.

So your array looks something like:

```
$myArrayOfDrinkImages = array(      
'iced-tea' => array('name' => 'Iced Teas', 
                    'thumb' => 'Pekoe_Menu_Drinks_Iced_Teas_Thumb4%20copy.jpg', 
                    'banner' => 'Pekoe_Menu_Drinks_Iced_Teas%20copy.jpg', 
                    'link' => 'http://somesiteurl.com', 
                    'blurb' => 'Fresh brewed in small batches and also available in bottles to take home.', 
                    'items' => array(   
                        'black-tiger', 
                        'forbidden-fruits', 
                        'pekoe-mate', 
                        'mango-mate', 
                        'paradise', 
                        'pekoe-rooibos', 
                        'sunny-green', 
                        'pekoe-palmers')
            );
'rum' => array(     ...etc
```

I've appended a new element to the array with the key 'link'.

Someplace later in your code (maybe some file with an .phtml extension or "view" script if this happens to be an MVC framework) that array is used to render the HTML of those images.  That code is probably something that loops over the array (maybe with some filtering as to what drinks to show) and outputs the markup.  As you've not provided that code I will show you a pseudo representation of what it may look like.

```
foreach ($myArrayOfDrinkImages as $drinkValues) {
    echo "<a href=\"{$drinkValues['link']}\"><img src="{$drinkValues['thumb']}" title=\"{$drinkValues['blurb']}\"/></a> ";
}
```

In summary you've not provided enough code to definitively answer anything.

Comment: You are providing bits and pieces.  Tired of formatting your code.  Suggest you hire a developer or ask one specific question and provide everything needed to answer it.  Sorry.  Also, the code you did provide already has a link wrapping the images.